# *Widely Recognizable* Icon for "Sensors"

Tags: icons

I am having a hard time finding a good and widely recognizable icon for Sensors. The icon needs to look good at small sizes (16x16 px.) A thermometer icon, while it is widely recognizable, probably would not work because this icon represents temperature, voltage, current, and power sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to a universal symbol for "sensor" might be a large dot/point and some waves moving away from it. [Example](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/ios7-icons-by-icons8/Industry-Rfid-Signal-icon.html)

Comment: What about this? - [http://i.imgur.com/io3IHyi.png](http://i.imgur.com/io3IHyi.png)

Comment: Not a bad choice either. See what works for your application.